# Wrong architecture or manufacturer - conflicting information

Tags: windows, cpu, architecture

This is what I get from the `set processor`(Environment variable) command in 64-bit Windows 7:

> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = **AMD64**
>
> PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = **Intel64** Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel

And this is what I get in "System Information":

> Processor: **Intel**(R) Core(TM) i3...

But how? What type of architecture and processor am I using?

Comment: **All** 64-bit x86 processors use the AMD 64-bit architecture.  You have an Intel i3.  The 64-bit extension to the x86 architecture is an AMD creation and thus Intel licenses it from AMD and extended it themselves.

Comment: This question has been asked before.  The major reason is that it shows virtually no research effort on your part.

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/179919/x86-vs-x64-why-is-32-bit-called-x86) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/854736/how-do-you-determine-that-your-hardware-is-64-bit-capable-when-there-is-no-opera) and the possible duplicate [here](http://superuser.com/questions/880370/x86-live-image-on-a-x64-processor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What type of architecture and processor am I using?

`wmic cpu` will give you a complete list of information regarding your processor.

Example output:

```
F:\test>wmic cpu get Description, Name
Description                           Name
Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.